# DeepNetts 1.3 is having issues with the serialization on the setEarlyStopping and writeToFile any network with ADAM optimizer

Tags: java, tensorflow, deep-learning, notserializableexception, deep-netts

This is my setup.
I'm trying to check every 5 epochs if I'm overfitting and using ADAM optimizer.
And trying to save the trained network to later usages.
Seems no matter the setup I can use ADAM optimizer it blow due to not being able to serialize.
I tried the Momentum backpropagation and it works, but I would like to use ADAM.

```
System.out.println("LOAD TRAINING DATA.");
        DataSet<MLDataItem> trainingSet = new TabularDataSet(d.inputs[0].length, d.outputs[0].length);
        trainingSet.setColumnNames(d.headers);
        for (int i = 0; i < d.inputs.length; i++) {

            trainingSet.add(new TabularDataSet.Item(d.inputs[i], d.outputs[i]));
        }

        System.out.println("NORMALIZING TRAINING DATA.");
        DataSets.normalizeMax(trainingSet);
        //trainingSet.getColumnNames();

        System.out.println("CREATING NETWORK.");
        neuralNet = FeedForwardNetwork.builder()
                .addInputLayer(d.inputs[0].length)
                .addFullyConnectedLayer(d.inputs[0].length, ActivationType.SIGMOID)
                .addFullyConnectedLayer((int) d.inputs[0].length / 2, ActivationType.SIGMOID)
                .addFullyConnectedLayer((int) d.inputs[0].length / 4, ActivationType.SIGMOID)
                .addOutputLayer(d.outputs[0].length, ActivationType.SIGMOID)
                .lossFunction(LossType.MEAN_SQUARED_ERROR)
                .randomSeed(123)
                .build();

        System.out.println("TRAINING CONFIGURATIONS.");
        neuralNet.setLabel("TRAINING DATA");
        BackpropagationTrainer trainer = neuralNet.getTrainer();
        trainer.setBatchMode(false);

        trainer.setEarlyStopping(true);
        trainer.setEarlyStoppingMinLossChange(0.00000001F);
        trainer.setEarlyStoppingPatience(5);

        trainer.setLearningRate(0.001F);
        trainer.setMaxEpochs(100);
        trainer.setMaxError(0.0001F);
        trainer.setMomentum(0F);

        trainer.setTrainingSnapshots(true);

        trainer.setOptimizer(OptimizerType.ADAM);
        System.out.println("TRAINING...");
        neuralNet.train(trainingSet);
        neuralNetFile = "neuralNetwork_" + timeStamp + ".dnet";

        System.out.println("SAVING NETWORK INTO " + neuralNetFile);
        FileIO.writeToFile(neuralNet, neuralNetFile);
        System.out.println("DONE!!!");
```

NotSerializable Exception on the earlyStopping

```
    at DeepNettsLearning.train(DeepNettsLearning.java:100) [classes/:?]
    at DeepNettsLearning.main(DeepNettsLearning.java:36) [classes/:?]
Epoch:20, Time:2ms, TrainError:0.053135615, TrainErrorChange:-0.0012555942, TrainAccuracy: 0.9285714
Epoch:21, Time:4ms, TrainError:0.0519301, TrainErrorChange:-0.0012055151, TrainAccuracy: 0.9285714
Epoch:22, Time:4ms, TrainError:0.050770074, TrainErrorChange:-0.0011600256, TrainAccuracy: 0.9285714
Epoch:23, Time:3ms, TrainError:0.049651828, TrainErrorChange:-0.0011182465, TrainAccuracy: 0.9285714
Epoch:24, Time:2ms, TrainError:0.048572194, TrainErrorChange:-0.0010796338, TrainAccuracy: 0.9285714
Catching
java.io.NotSerializableException: deepnetts.net.train.opt.AdamOptimizer
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1193) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1579) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1536) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1444) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1187) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1579) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1536) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1444) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1187) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1579) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1536) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1444) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1187) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1579) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1536) ~[?:?]
```

And also when saving to file

```
Total Training Time: 595ms
------------------------------------------------------------------------
SAVING NETWORK INTO neuralNetwork_2021.03.19.17.31.37.dnet
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: deepnetts.net.train.opt.AdamOptimizer
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1193)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1579)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1536)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1444)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1187)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1579)
```

Anyone can help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I've just created the `deep-netts` tag, I couldn't find any other questions or answers on this topic. If you have some ideas how to ping anyone knowledgeable about Deep Netts on any other medium, you might consider doing that, just to get some Deep-Nets related activity going here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like DeepNetts have a bug in their code. I've checked their GitHub and there is no adam optimizer, so I assume you are using professional edition

Could you ask their support about this issue?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the professional but under the development license. It's true that the community edition doesn't have the ADAM, and seems the professional is not working either. Even using the DeepNetts Platform (GUI) I can create the network file there but I can't either save the file or load on my Java app.